# Some example of JUnit of Rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, junit

I wanna to try some example of JUnit with rest API, I am a beginner of JUnit and I don't know how to start

My Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<ClienteEntity, Integer>{
    ClienteEntity findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);


     @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM ClienteEntity u where u.email = ?1 and u.password = ?2 ")
        Optional<ClienteEntity> login(String email,String password);

        Optional<ClienteEntity> findByToken(String token);



        @Query(value = "SELECT c " +  
                "FROM ClienteEntity c " +
                "WHERE c.id = :id ")

        ClienteEntity getClienteById(@Param("id")Integer id);



}
```

Had an entity "cliente" with these fields:

```
@Entity(name = "cliente")
public class cliente{
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) //Vedere UUID bene
    private Integer id;

    private String nome;

    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email ;

    private String password;

    private String citta;

    private String cap;

    private String indirizzo;

    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}

//with their set and get methods
```

Is it possible to test the **email** of a **user** in **cliente** in the fields instead of my DB

Comment: You question is not that clear, but if you are totally unexperienced with JUnit, please refer to documentation first to get a basic understanding. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Comment: You could found here some basics about how to use JUnit with Spring https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples you will get by goggle :). But you might not be expecting such answer from me !

Now lengthy but detailed answer have patience :P

You can do JUnitTesting using junit, mockito, spring test, power-mockito etc.

As I am assuming your Rest Project Structure is :-

```
1. Controller is :- 

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestApiController {

    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println();
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

2. Service Layer is :-

    @Service("userService")
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

       @Autowired
       UserDao userDao;

       public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return userDao.findAll();
       }
    }
}
```

3. Dao Layer:-

   Same as yours.

Now Making Unit Test of It:-

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = RestController.class, secure = false)
public class RestControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@SpyBean
private RestApiController restController;

@SpyBean
private UserServiceImpl userService;   //Spy will call real method (Use Spy where you want actual execution).

@MockBean
UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl; ( Use Mock where you don't want execution as in your case you don't want to make query in database.)  --Use Mock and step 1 define rule which will give expected result without real execution. 
// How you will know :- If you place debug and run as debug junit you will find debugger will not go method inside in mocked object)

@Test
public void testListAllUsers(){
    List<User> userList= new ArrayList<User>();
    userList.add(new User(1, "himanshu", 26, "abc@gmail.com"));
    Mockito.when(userDaoImpl.findAll()).thenReturn(userList);    //step 1 
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, restController.listAllUsers().getStatusCode());    // This will check if expected status code is present in response --Happy Case


    Assert.assertEquals("himanshu", restController.listAllUsers().getBody().get(0).getName());  // if you also want to test whether object in happy case has valid attribute.
    System.out.println(" completed");
}

}
```

If you want to Test rest call using URL :-

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
            "/api/user/").accept(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    Assert.assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
```

Reference Link:-
Mocktio : https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html
Spring Testing :- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html

Maven Dependency:-
For Spring Test:-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For Mockito Test:-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The above example will test whole (controller-service-dao) flow but if you want to do seperate module test which is easy and for that you have make DaoTest class and mock Dao layer and do test similarly which is not good approach.

Testing from (controller - service -dao) appear integration testing which itself test all the individual modules automatically.

Cheers !!